# Benefits of a Factory for model instantiation without need for creation logic

Tags: c#, factory-method

With DDD and some of the other abstraction principles out there, when the need arises to instantiate unstable instances (negating stable C# instantiation and primitives), the logic for Factory pattern makes sense (at times) when needing to define business logic while instantiating (security benefits, performance with possibly not needing memory allocations for new, etc.), however, what if the instance does not require any instantiation logic, but itself as well as other related models are used in multiple places in the same class (Example being the very simplified code created below ... changing public to least privileges where applicable, etc.)

Are there benefits of abstracting out the instantiation into a factory pattern as opposed to inline instantiation (be it dependency inversion or other)? ... most searches I've found touch on the pros and cons of the factory pattern, the alternatives, static vs DI (Bloch's Effective Java), etc.

```
   public interface IUserTypeFactory
    {
        User CreateUser();
        Admin CreateAdmin();
        Reporter CreateReporter();
    }

   public class UserTypeFactory : IUserTypeFactory
    {
        public User CreateUser() => new User();
        public Admin CreateAdmin() => new Admin();
        public Reporter CreateReporter() => new Reporter();
    }

   public class UserService
   {
       private readonly IUserTypeFactory _userTypeFactory;

       public UserService(IUserTypeFactory userTypeFactory) => _userTypeFactory = userTypeFactory;

        public void DoSomething()
       {
           var user = _userTypeFactory.CreateUser();
           // .. business logic
       }

       // More Methods requiring instantiation
   }
```

Comment: It's was a reference to Uncle Bob's [Clean Architecture](https://www.amazon.com/Clean-Architecture-Craftsmans-Software-Structure/dp/0134494164). Framework classes and properties (ex. String is stable as the kinks have been worked out). While developing, classes and properties might change, making that instantiated object unstable and abstracting logic into a factory makes (potentially not always) the non-factory class more stable since the associated unstable logic is put into a factory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two benefits, one somewhat abstract and one practical.

1. Object instantiation is a separate responsibility. Under SRP, your business logic code should not be doing it. The responsibility of object creation belongs to the composition root and to factories.
2. If your code uses `new` there is more or less no way to substitute another class for unit testing. If your code uses an `IXXXFactory` of some kind, your unit test code can supply its own factory which would return mock or stub objects, allowing you to isolate the class under test. This makes unit testing much easier.

Comment: Further to this you can also return decorator classes that implement the same interface that add logging or security, as a couple of examples, to the underlying object.